Prove or disprove: limit of a polar graph is the unit disk
Let $r:[0,\Theta]\to [0,1]$ and $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the defined as follows:
$$r(\theta)=\theta-\lfloor\theta\rfloor \\
D = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\ |\ x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$$
Note that $D$ is the unit disk. Draw a polar graph of $r(\theta)$ for every $\theta\in[0,\Theta]$. Namely, draw all the points in this set:
$$R(\Theta)=\{(x,y)=(r(\theta)\cos(\theta),r(\theta)\sin(\theta))\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ \forall\theta\in[0,\Theta]\}$$
Prove or disprove:
$$\lim_{\Theta\to\infty}R(\Theta)=D$$
By editing this post over and over with my (suddenly) new thoughts, I think I can disprove this, but I need your affirmation.
The way I thought of proving this is the following: for every $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, create a sequence $a_n(\theta)=\theta+2\pi n$ (of course $n\geq 0$) and look at the following group:
$$A(\theta)=\{r[a_n(\theta)]\ | \ n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$$
If we prove $A(\theta)=(0,1]$ for every $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, then we cover the unit disk with lines that go through the origin (given that the origin itself is also attained for some $\theta_0$). It's important to state that this claim and the original claim are equivalent, meaning:
$$\lim_{\Theta\to\infty}R(\Theta)=D \iff A(\theta)=(0,1]\ (\text{or }[0,1])\ \forall\theta\in[0,2\pi) \text{ and } \exists\theta_0\in\mathbb{R}^+:r(\theta_0)=0$$
Obviously we can choose $\theta_0=0$. Now, we need to show that given an arbitrary pair $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ and $x\in(0,1]$, there exists an $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that:
$$\theta+2\pi n-\lfloor\theta+2\pi n\rfloor=x$$
The solutions to this equation are given by:
$$\theta+2\pi n=x+m\qquad \ \ \ \ \  \forall m\in\mathbb{Z}^+ \\ \implies n=\frac{x+m-\theta}{2\pi}\quad \forall m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$$
Which means that we need to show that there exists an $m_0\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that:
$$\frac{x+m_0-\theta}{2\pi}\in\mathbb{Z}^+$$
But I'm pretty sure this can be countered. For example, given $\theta=0$ and $x=1$, we'd have to find an $m_0\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that:
$$1+m\in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$$
But this would mean that $\pi$ is rational.

I have no idea what this means, what is a polar graph of $r$??? How is $R(\Theta)$ a group? Was this generated by chatgpt?

Correct me if I'm wrong: You are basically asking if for all $\epsilon>0$, $r\in [0,1]$ and $\phi\in [0,2\pi)$ there exists $\theta$ such that the distance between $(r\sin(\phi),r\cos(\phi))$ and $((\theta-\lfloor \theta \rfloor)\sin(\theta),(\theta-\lfloor \theta \rfloor)\cos(\theta))$ is less than $\epsilon$?

@copper.hat - by "polar graph" Amit means a graph with polar coordinates $r(\theta)$ and $\theta$. And they are using "group" to mean "set" rather than an algebraic group. These are likely problems with translation into English from another language.

Any value of $\theta_0$ defines a ray eminating from the origin pointing in some direction. The other values of $\theta$ that define the same ray differ from it by $2\pi m$ for some integer $m$. There are only countably many such values, so only countably many values for $r = \theta_0 + 2\pi m - \lfloor \theta_0 + 2\pi m\rfloor$ for points on this ray in $R(\Theta)$.
But $D$ has uncountably many points on the ray, one for every $r \in [0,1]$. Thus $R(\Theta)$ cannot be all of $D$. Nor is $R = \{(r(\theta)\cos \theta, r(\theta)\sin \theta) : \theta \in \Bbb R\}$, which is a superset of the limit of $R(\Theta)$.
What is true is that the closure of $\lim_{\Theta \to \infty}R(\Theta)$ is all of $D$.
